# What is the typical concentration of Calcineurin (PP2B) in CA1 dendritic spines?

Tags: molecular-biology

I am trying to find the concentration of CaN (PP2B) in dendritic spines, there is a computational model (doi:10.1073/pnas.0804672105) that uses the quantity of 1uM in the dendritic spine. I think this value is not correct since it was measured long time ago (Goto Brain Res. 1986 Nov 5;397(1):161-72) and was given as Hippocampus 1.45 -+ 0.39 (ug/mg of protein).

Comment: Why do you think the data is *incorrect* simply because it is old? The concentration can be high because the volume of the dendritic spine is very less.

Comment: [This](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3221876/) article says that CamKII concentration (different subunits) is ~60-140µM. Calcineurin should be in similar range, I guess.

Comment: I think that this measurement is incorrect for the spine because CaN localization is found in the spine neighborhood, not the whole neuron (that diluted the concentration). Being old is not a problem, sometimes it is gold, like Magee and Johnston (1995) VGCC measurements. A Lisman paper guesses that CaN concentration is maybe 20uM in the spine (CA1), but they don't provide the reference ...

Comment: Do you know how CaN and CamKII are correlated? I could not find any article on CaN concentrations but see my previous comment for CamKII concentration. You can at least make an informed guess for your computational model. I do believe, you would do some kind of sensitivity analysis with your model parameters; so a perfect value may not be essential.

Comment: How they are correlated? one is a phosphatase that presumably dephosphorylates (CaMKII), an experiment in 2015 is saying that is not the case but they didn't look into the dynamics with enough temporal resolution, as Chang/Yasuda 2017 did. For CaMKII there are several estimations of the spine concentration, which is really good. For CaN, the spine concentration is hard to trust. And there are values in literature from 1uM to 20uM.

Comment: Kuno et al., J Neurochem, 1992, PMID 1313851 give 0.96 % total hippocampal protein = calcineurin (both isoforms). 
Goto et al., 1986 give ~ 0.15 % total protein = calcineurin
In rat brain, there is ~ 10 % protein / total wet weight (Clouet & Gaitonde, PMID 13398827).
Stefan, PNAS, 2008. 1uM
Lisman and Pi, 2008. 20uM

Comment: I don't know how they are correlated; not my area of expertise. I just suggested if you know there is a correlation then you can guess an approximate value.

Comment: Thanks! I will let this rest on my head.